# JOIN table if condition is satisfied, else perform no join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have one table `transaction` and another table `transaction_item`.

One transaction has multiple transaction_items.

I want to left join `transaction_item` if `transaction_item.amount >= 2`, else perform no join.

```
select ti.*
from transaction t
LEFT JOIN transaction_item ti on ti.unique_id = t.unique_id  
    AND ti.location_id =  t.location_id 
    AND ti.transaction_date = t.transaction_date
    AND ti.amount >= 2
where t.pos_transaction_id = 4220
and t.location_id = 1674
and t.transaction_date = '2020-05-08';
```

If I do it this way it is results in 15 rows in place of total 20 rows, because 20 rows are in `transaction_item` table corresponding to `transaction_id` 4220. But I want no join in this case because 5 rows in `transaction_item` have `amount < 2`.

Comment: please post your table structure and sample data with sample output

Comment: You should familiarize yourself how SQL statements work - first all required tables are joined, then from this gigantic `virtual` table some rows are filtered/excluded based on your conditions in the WHERE clause, then the remaining rows are grouped according to your GROUP BY clause, then the result of the grouping is filtered again - according to your HAVING clause. And finally from this result some rows are fetched according to your LIMIT clause. So if you want to conditionally JOIN 2 tables - the condition must be specified after the `ON` keyword.

Comment: If I am following your description correctly, you should be getting 20 rows, but 5 of them consist entirely of NULL values and perhaps you are not recognizing them as being rows.  It generally does not make sense to do a LEFT JOIN in which your SELECT list consists entirely of column from the right-hand-side table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description a bit confusing, but the title says:
***"else perform no join"***

So I think you want something this:

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM   transaction t
LEFT   JOIN transaction_item ti ON ti.unique_id        = t.unique_id  
                               AND ti.location_id      = t.location_id 
                               AND ti.transaction_date = t.transaction_date
                               AND NOT EXISTS (
                                    SELECT FROM transaction_item tx
                                    WHERE  tx.unique_id        = t.unique_id  
                                    AND    tx.location_id      = t.location_id 
                                    AND    tx.transaction_date = t.transaction_date
                                    AND    tx.amount < 2)  -- !
WHERE  t.pos_transaction_id = 4220
AND    t.location_id = 1674
AND    t.transaction_date = '2020-05-08';
```

However, the `LEFT JOIN` in combination with only columns from the *right* table in the `SELECT` list is dubious at best. This way you get one row with all NULL values for every row in `transaction` that qualifies and has no matching rows in `transaction_item` *or* one or more matching rows with `amount < 2`. I doubt you want *that*.

Typically, you'll want to include columns from `transaction` in the `SELECT` list, or use an `[INNER] JOIN` instead.

So it could be:

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM   transaction t
JOIN   transaction_item ti USING (unique_id, location_id, transaction_date)
WHERE  t.pos_transaction_id = 4220
AND    t.location_id = 1674
AND    t.transaction_date = '2020-05-08';
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM transaction_item tx
   WHERE  tx.unique_id        = t.unique_id  
   AND    tx.location_id      = t.location_id 
   AND    tx.transaction_date = t.transaction_date
   AND    tx.amount < 2);
```

Then again, a table `transaction_item` would typically have a FK column `transaction_id` referencing `transaction` - in which case we can simplify

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM   transaction t
JOIN   transaction_item ti ON ti.transaction_id = t.transaction_id -- ?
WHERE  t.pos_transaction_id = 4220
AND    t.location_id = 1674
AND    t.transaction_date = '2020-05-08';
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM transaction_item tx
   WHERE  tx.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
   AND    tx.amount < 2);
```

You mentioned both `pos_transaction_id` and `transaction_id`, so I am guessing here ...

The major insight to take away from this: ***always*** show exact table definitions with any such question.