# show records that have only one matchin row in another table

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a  sql code that probably is very simple but I am very new to it.
I need to find all the records from one table that have matching id (but no more than one) from the other table. eg. one table contains records of the employees and the second one  with employees' telephone numbers. i need to find all employees with only one telephone no

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62704113/12859753) answer your question?

Comment: @Bill: Interesting, but different question.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data would be nice. In absence of:

```
SELECT
   employees.employee_id
FROM 
   employees 
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT distinct on(employee_id) employee_id FROM emp_phone) AS phone
ON
   employees.employee_id = phone.employee_id
WHERE
    phone.employee_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join` of the 2 tables, `group by` employee and the condition in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.name
FROM employees e INNER JOIN numbers n
ON e.employee_id = n.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there can be more than a few numbers per employee in the table with the employees' telephone numbers (calling it `tel`), then it's cheaper to avoid `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` which has to process all rows. Find employees with "unique" numbers using a self-anti-join with `NOT EXISTS`.

While you don't need more than the `employee_id` and their unique phone number, you don't even have to involve the `employee` table at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tel t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tel
   WHERE  employee_id = t.employee_id
   AND    tel_number <> t.tel_number  -- or use PK column
   );
```

If you need additional columns from the employee table:

```
SELECT *  -- or any columns you need
FROM  (
   SELECT employee_id AS id, tel_number  -- or any columns you need
   FROM   tel t
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM tel
      WHERE  employee_id = t.employee_id
      AND    tel_number <> t.tel_number  -- or use PK column
      )
   ) t
JOIN   employee e USING (id);
```

The column alias in the subquery (`employee_id AS id`) is just for convenience. Then the outer join condition can be `USING (id)`, and the ID column is only included once in the result, even with `SELECT *` ...

Simpler with a smart naming convention that uses `employee_id` for the employee ID everywhere. But it's a widespread anti-pattern to use `employee.id` instead.

Related:

- [JOIN table if condition is satisfied, else perform no join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300612/join-table-if-condition-is-satisfied-else-perform-no-join/62313590#62313590)